# iOS -> .NET WebService authentication question

Tags: iphone, web-services, security, ios

I'm building an iOS app which will communicate with a set of .NET WebServices.  I'm trying to find a way to ensure on the WS side that the calls being sent actually came from the iOS app.

There is, of course, a "login" method which requires a username/password combination.  I would like to add a "security token" to this method, which I can use to validate that the request is coming from the iOS app.

Since this is a parameter to the login method, is must be something known by the app and the web service BEFORE a valid login occurs.  Additionally, it should be something which is impossible (difficult?) for another application to fake.

Are their any best practices / standard methods for this sort of exchange?  Am I even thinking about the problem in the correct way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the oAuth specification (used by Twitter) it requires that a user is verified first, during the process a series of tokens are exchanged, and then the token is used to sign the data during subsequent data exchanges.

It works on the principals of public/private matched keys, so you have one key that is always kept a secret.

Comment: In this case there is no third party which needs access to some data.  There is simply my iPhone app and the webservice.  Would oAuth still be a valid solution?

Comment: I don't think oAuth will work, as there isn't a third party to verify against.  What I'm trying to do is ensure that the calls being made to the WS are actually coming from the software we've built (which lives on the iPhone.  oAuth doesn't seem to do that.  (Unless I'm missing something!)

Comment: FYI - I decided to use public / private key encryption to accomplish this.  Thanks!